# Angular: Reference query params in redirectTo

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-router

I would like to provide a path that redirects to a given page based on query parameters. For example:

```
/redirect?page=hero&id=1
```

should redirect to:

```
/hero/1
```

Is there any way to do this in the route config? Something like:

```
{ path: 'redirect?page&id', redirectTo: ':page/:id' }
```

I can get the **redirectTo** to respect path parameters but not query parameters. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `redirectTo: '/:page/:id'` and provide extracted from your URL `page` and `id` values using custom [`UrlMatcher()`](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher):

```
...

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'hero/:id',
    component: TestComponent
  },
  {
    matcher: redirectMatcher,
    redirectTo: '/:page/:id'
  }
];

...

/**
 * custom url matcher for router config
 */
export function redirectMatcher(url: UrlSegment[]) {
  if (url[0] && url[0].path.includes('redirect')) {
    const path = url[0].path;
    // sanity check
    if (path.includes('page') && path.includes('id')) {
      return {
        consumed: url,
        posParams: {
          page: new UrlSegment(path.match(/page=([^&]*)/)[1], {}),
          id: new UrlSegment(path.match(/id=([^&]*)/)[1], {})
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

STACKBLITZ: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t3tsak?file=app%2Ftest.component.ts

There is another issue when using `redirectTo: ...`, active link is not updated, actually `isActive` flag is not set to `true`, it is seen on my stackblitz when acrive redirection links are not colored in red

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way of doing it by a configuration. YOu see, Angular's router does not explicitly define query parameters - any url can have an arbitrary number of query params, and the paths '/page/id' and '/page/id?key=value' are treated as the same in Angular and do map to the same component. There are other, more cumbersome workarounds. One is to create a dummy component and redirect based on `ActivatedRoute.queryParams` Observable from the component's `ngOnInit` method. You can easily see why this is a bad idea. 
Another way is to create a resolver, this way you maybe can dismiss the component declaration and just redirect from the resolver, again, based on the `ActivatedRoute.queryParams` Observable, which seems cleaner.

But I do not really get why one would need such a route in a front end application, if you want someone to visit '/page/id', then just navigate them to the page, without any intermediary tricks.

Comment: Makes sense. Unfortunately, the legacy application doing the navigating only supports dynamic query parameters and not path parameters. :/

Comment: Please check my answer with `UrlMatcher` solution

Answer (score 0):

```
this.router.navigate(['/inform/page'], { queryParams: { community: 970 } });
```